# Java Media Framework: how to get framerate from videostream

Tags: java, video, jmf

I am using the Java Media Framework to play a video file.

Now I would like to know the framerate of the videostream?

How is that possible? Thanks!

edit:
instances of the following are available:

```
javax.media.Manager
javax.media.MediaLocator
javax.media.NoProcessorException
javax.media.Processor
```

Comment: If you post some code of what you already have, I'm pretty sure we will be able to help you.

Comment: do not use JMF it does not support wide camera you will see it works with few but in production level you will suffer with nightmares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following

```
        try {
            Processor myProcessor = Manager.createProcessor( myMediaLocator );
            Format relax = myProcessor.getContentDescriptor().relax();
            if(relax instanceof VideoFormat) {
                double frameRate = ((VideoFormat)relax).getFrameRate();
            }
        } catch( NoProcessorException e ) {
        } catch( NotConfiguredError e ) {
        } catch( IOException e ) {
        }
```

or perhaps form the content descriptor form the DataSource. For `URLDataSource`:

```
DataSource dataSource = myProcessor.getDataOutput();
if(dataSource instanceof URLDataSource){
    PullSourceStream[] streams = ((URLDataSource)dataSource).getStreams();
    if(streams.length > 0){
        Format relax = streams[0].getContentDescriptor().relax();
        if(relax instanceof VideoFormat) {
            System.out.println(((VideoFormat)relax).getFrameRate());
        }
    }
}
```

or at least, try to get the Format from the `javax.media.Buffer`:

```
DataSource dataSource = myProcessor.getDataOutput();
if(dataSource instanceof PullBufferDataSource){ // or PushBufferDataSource
    PullBufferStream[] streams = ((PullBufferDataSource)dataSource).getStreams();
    if(streams.length > 0){
        Format relax = streams[0].getFormat();
        if(relax instanceof VideoFormat) {
            System.out.println(((VideoFormat)relax).getFrameRate());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its nice you coded. But do not use JMF, Oracle drop there development on this.